# why does creating an nsarray of file names crash my app when document directory is empty?

Tags: iphone, crash, document

ok i've been going round in circles for 1.5 hours, now i need some help. below is the code i'm using to create a list of files in my Documents Directory, all works fine unless the directory is empty.

```
fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
```

what can i do directly before this to check if the directory has contents?

ive tried

```
if ([[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error] objectAtIndex:0]){
fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
}
```

but that also crashes the app

/////////////////////NOOB MISTAKE ALERT////////////////////

ok my problem was my next line of code

```
NSLog(@"fileList: %@",[fileList objectAtIndex:fileList.count-1]);
```

that's what was crashing my app, my own fault i admit lol. [fileList objectAtIndex:fileList.count-1] is out of bounds, i'm confused as to why the debugger didn't tell me that much.

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: You don't need to check if the directory is empty first. You get an empty array if there is nothing in there. Are you by any chance accessing [fileList objectAtIndex:0] or similar in the next line? What is the crash you are getting?

Comment: unfortunately the app crashes with no error in the debugger, ive edited question to answer your first query.

Comment: put a breakpoint at the array and check. Also you need to check if the array is empty so put condition accordingly.

Comment: and check what? and the condition is correct, isnt it?

Comment: the second example is definitely going to crash - you are trying to access object at index 0 from an empty array. There is nothing in an empty array, so this is outside the bounds. Try typing `bt` in the debugger console to get a backtrace if you can't see any error in the console.

Comment: bt doesn't list anything, it just returns a new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method should not crash even if there is no files. According to the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSFileManager),

```
... Returns an empty array if the directory exists but has no contents.
```

I would check

- If the `documentsDirectory` variable is properly set as a NSString instance
- If the `documentsDirectory` variable is not deallocated already

NSLogging `documentsDirectory` just before the call would be the right first step.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using returns an empty array if the directory has no content.

Before attempting to access anything from the array, check its `count` to make sure that something is present:

```
if ([fileList count] == 0)
    // You have an empty directory
```

Comment: it crashes before i can get a count, it crashes whilst creating fileList

Comment: how and where are you declaring fileList? And did you try the `bt` in the debugger console?

Comment: bt doesn't list anything, it just returns a new line